# JavaBridge don't open php (Could not connect to server)

Tags: java, php, tomcat, php-java-bridge

I'm trying to run php on Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 using JavaBridgeTemplate621.

But when I go to the **localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate621/index.php** I saw this:

> HTTP Status 500 - php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server

OS is Ubuntu. PHP Version 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.6. PHP is working: **phpinfo()** function shows my PHP config (**localhost/test.php**)

How can I fix it?

P.S. I heard that I must put **php-cgi** to the **/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/JavaBridgeTemplate621/WEB-INF/cgi/i386-linux**. Where can I take it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix it by myself :)

[This method](http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/run-php-applications-in-tomcat-7-with-php-java-bridge) was very useful, problem has gone.